# Angular2 Routing How can i separate Routing Links And HtmlPages load

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

[image]Here I'm Doing Angular2 Routing When i Load my Links in nva-bar Under  same Html Page is also Load under   please Help me How can Separate These two

```
<nav>
<li> <a [routerLink]="['Employee/Add']" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Employee</a></li>
 <li> <a [routerLink]="['HrModule/Add']" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">HrModule</a></li>
</nav>

<div>
    <router-outlet>

    </router-outlet>
</div>
```

**AppComponent.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core"
@Component({
    selector:"customer-ui",
    templateUrl:"../../templates/Master.html"
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

Comment: `Here I'm Doing Angular2 Routing When i Load my Links in nva-bar Under same Html Page is also Load under please Help me How can Separate These two` what does this mean ? are both the pages loaded one after another ? in the same page

Comment: Hai Rahul singh i Found Answer I Just Separate These Div   If u want im Readdy to Ans